# Name of a named pipe given handle

Tags: c++, winapi, named-pipes

I'm trying to find the name of a named pipe given it's handle.  I found a solution where the named pipe handle is duplicated using NtDuplicateObject and then the name is extracted using NtQueryObject but it's unstable so that's out of the question.

Currently I'm attempting to do so with GetFinalPathNameByHandle but having no luck.  I'm not even sure if it's possible to do this but it was mentioned as a potential solution so I'm going with it.  The following is adapted from the example code at:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364962(v=vs.85).aspx

```
void __cdecl _tmain(int argc, TCHAR *argv[]){
   TCHAR Path[BUFSIZE];
   HANDLE pipe;
   DWORD dwRet;

   printf("\n");
   if (argc != 2)
   {
      printf("ERROR:\tIncorrect number of arguments\n\n");
      printf("%s <file_name>\n", argv[0]);
      return;
   }

   pipe = CreateNamedPipe(argv[1], PIPE_ACCESS_INBOUND | PIPE_ACCESS_OUTBOUND, PIPE_WAIT, 1,
          1024, 1024, 120 * 1000, NULL);

   if (pipe == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
   {
      printf("Could not open file (error %d\n)", GetLastError());
      return;
   }

   dwRet = GetFinalPathNameByHandle(pipe, Path, BUFSIZE, VOLUME_NAME_NT);
   if (dwRet < BUFSIZE)
   {
      _tprintf(TEXT("\nThe final path is: %s\n"), Path);
   }
   else printf("\nThe required buffer size is %d.\n", dwRet);

   CloseHandle(pipe);}
```

The command line parameter is "\\\\.\\pipe\\mynamedpipe" or "\\.\pipe\mynamedpipe", I've tried both.  The output is garbage but more importantly when debugging with Visual Studio 2013 Express while stepping through the program the path variable is garbage directly after the GetFinalPathNameByHandle call.

By garbage I mean:

- Path    0x0036fab4 L"쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌...    wchar_t[100]

Console output is:

- The final path is:  ?????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????6?╫☻

So I'm officially stuck.  Alternatively and possibly a much better solution would be comparing two named pipe handles to each other to determine if they point to the same named pipe.  If there is a way to do that it would solve my problem as well.

Comment: GetFinalPathNameByHandle is most likely return 0 which means it encountered an error.  When GetFinalPathNameByHandle returns 0 call GetLastError() to get the error code.  That may give you more information.

Comment: It does in fact return 0.  GetLastError() returns 1.  I assume that refers to the 1st error return code of GetFinalBathNameByHandle which is ERROR_PATH_NOT_FOUND?

Comment: The function probably only works for file system paths, not any other type of handle.  So you'll probably going down the wrong path.

Comment: OK then, this entire line of thinking is a bust.  Any thoughts on comparing two Handles to determine if they point towards the same named pipe?

Comment: `GetLastError()` returns an actual error code, not something like "the 1st error return code of ...".  Error Code 1 is `ERROR_INVALID_FUNCTION`, whereas `ERROR_PATH_NOT_FOUND` is Error Code 3.  Look in `winerror.h` for the actual error code definitions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer my own question here.  [GetFileInformationByHandleEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364953(v=vs.85).aspx) does exactly this using FileNameInfo for the FileInformationClass parameter and a handle generated by CreateNamedPipe.

Comment: Interestingly, [the current page for that API method (dated 12/05/2018)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-getfileinformationbyhandleex) explicitly says _"This handle should not be a pipe handle"_, but it indeed does return the name (the part after the typical `\\.\pipe` (or `\Device\NamedPipe` if you're a Process Explorer user) of a local pipe)